# My spell checker on my python calculator won't work

Tags: python

I've done a spelling mistake checker so that I don't get a bunch of error when one is made, but I seem to have screwed it up without knowing how and now I get a false reading every time.

I tried to fix it by changing everything.

I use this code

```
# Ask the user for the type of operation
    operation = input("Enter 'add', 'subtract', 'multiply', or 'divide': ").lower()
    if operation == "add":
        result = first_number + second_number
    elif operation == "subtract":
        result = first_number - second_number
    elif operation == "multiply":
        result  = first_number * second_number
    elif operation == "divide": 
        result = first_number / second_number

    # A spell checker to make sure the text input is a good one
    if not operation == ("add", "subtract", "multiply", "divide"):
        print("Invalid operation")
        return
    else:
        return(result)
```

I tried using another function than if not, and all sorts of other things but nothing seemed to work

Comment: Use `if operation not in`. You are asking your code if your user's input is equal to the whole value of `("add", "subtract", "multiply", "divide")`...this can't be accurate. You need to see if it is `in` the iterable not `==` equal to

Comment: Or better yet, the dedicated `not in` operator shown in my answer.

Comment: Or better yet, just use `else: print("Invalid operation")`, because you have previously checked all the valid options.

Comment: I linked a duplicate that shows you how to check if `operation` is one of the given choices, but inverting that condition is quite easy: `not in` instead of `in`

Comment: Your `if-elif` chain is already testing if the input is one of "add", "subtract", "multiply", "divide" so there is no point in testing again. You can simply add an `else` statement at the end of the chain to print the error message and return, then finally return the result which will only be reached if the error has not be activated.

Answer (score 0):

`operation == ("add", "subtract", "multiply", "divide")` is checking if the string `operation` is equal to the entire tuple on the right of the `==`. A string can't be equal to a tuple though, so that check will always be false. In your case, since you're negating using `not`, that means that check will always be `True`.

Instead, you want to check if the string is `not in` the tuple:

```
if operation not in ("add", "subtract", "multiply", "divide"):
```